# how does synthesis translate_off work?

Tags: vhdl, implementation, fpga, synthesis

I have a code with the following structure

```
-- synthesis translate_off
... some sort of memory implementation/coding
-- synthesis translate_on
```

Please let me know if deleting this piece of code will affect the final output from my **`FPGA implementation`** of the code.

Thanks,
Best regards,
Faras

Comment: simply put the code falling between the two pragma comments would not result in hardware.  Typically the code in there is for simulation purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The metacomments `synthesis translate_off` and `... _on` are not part of the
VHDL synthesis standard (IEEE P1076.6), so behaviour is tool dependent.

For example, Altera Quartus II documentation describes [translate_off and translate_on VHDL Synthesis Directives](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_file_dir_translate.htm), saying

> ... direct Analysis & Synthesis to ignore portions of the design code ... The text between the directives is treated as if each line is preceded by a single-line comment delimiter. ...

So deleting the code between the directives will not affect the final synthesis output.

For a discussion about generally applicable metacomments, you may read this description by Sigasi: [List of known VHDL metacomment
pragma's](http://www.sigasi.com/content/list-known-vhdl-metacomment-pragmas).

VHDL synthesis standard (IEEE P1076.6) prescribes use of `rtl_synthesis off`
and `... on`, but according to Sigasi, this does not appear to be well
supported.

As a final word, then the ignore directives should be used with caution, since they may (will) cause design in simulation and design in synthesis to behave differently, thus impeding verification and debug of the design.

Answer (score 0):

VHDL synthesis directives that direct Analysis & Synthesis to ignore portions of the design code that are specific to simulation and not relevant to logic synthesis.

To use the translate_off and translate_on synthesis directives, you can specify the translate_off synthesis directive in a comment located immediately before the code you want Analysis & Synthesis to ignore, and specify the translate_on synthesis directive in a comment located immediately after the code you want Analysis & Synthesis to ignore. In the comment, precede the synthesis directive with the synthesis keyword. The text between the directives is treated as if each line is preceded by a single-line comment delimiter. Syntax checking is not performed and there is no requirement that the text be valid VHDL.

Note: Analysis & Synthesis also recognizes the synonymous synthesis directives synthesis_off and synthesis_on. These synthesis directives behave identically to the translate_off and translate_on synthesis directives.

For example, in the following code, Analysis & Synthesis ignores the code USE std.textio.all;, and performs logic synthesis on any code after the comment -- synthesis translate_on (unless the user uses the translate_off and translate_on synthesis directives again):

-- synthesis translate_off

USE std.textio.all;

-- synthesis translate_on

You can use the Ignore translate_off and translate_on Synthesis Directives logic option to disable all translate_off and translate_on synthesis directives in a design, allowing you to use the sections previously ignored during a compilation.